# Dynamic import from node_modules is not working

Tags: vue.js, webpack, node-modules, dynamic-import

I made a vue component package `my-custom-comp`, which contains dynamic import:
`my-custom-comp.vue`

```
<template>
  <component v-if="id && data" :is="`list-${id}`" :data="data" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['id','data'],
  components: {
    'list-1': () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "MyTaglist0" */'./list-1.vue'),
    'list-2': () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "MyTaglist0" */'./list-2.vue'),
    'list-3': () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "MyTaglist1" */'./list-3.vue'),
    'list-4': () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "MyTaglist1" */'./list-4.vue')
  }
}
</script>
```

Output files in lib:

```
  my-custom-comp.common.js
  my-custom-comp.common.MyTaglist0.js
  my-custom-comp.common.MyTaglist1.js
```

I have `my-custom-comp` package installed in my app, and add package path to  `resolve.modules`:
`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules'), path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/my-custom-comp/lib')],
  }
  ...
}
```

but `MyTaglist0.js` can't be resolved:

```
GET http://localhost:8882/my-custom-comp.common.MyTaglist0.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

How to resolve dynamic import  from node_modules?

Test Repo:
https://github.com/Miaoxingren/webpack-issue-8934

Comment: Jsfiddle or Codesandbox would really hep here!

Comment: Please look at this [test repo](https://github.com/Miaoxingren/webpack-issue-8934).